# El form no espera a darle al botón

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap

tengo un problema con la comprobación de un formulario en html, lo que quiero es evitar que la pagina se recargue al enviar el formulario, pues la idea es que se cierre el modal y se abra otro en el lado derecho de la pantalla, para el ello estuve mirando y había que añadir action="javascript:void(0);" al form. Pero ahora al escribir en los campos, automáticamente carga los links de prueba sin esperar a darle al botón. Me gustaría saber el porque pasa esto. Aparte de saber como cerrar y abrir el modal desde el código.
Los modals son de bootstrap.

#---Edit---#

El Username no esta comprobando correctamente lo que se escribe en el campo, pues al escribir e que es lo que se espera, sigue entrando en el else. Tambien se ha eliminado el action del form debido a una respuesta, pero sigue sin funcionar. ¿Porque el .getElementById no esta devolviendo el texto del campo correspondiente?

```js
    const Username = document.getElementById("Username");
    const password = document.getElementById("input-pass");
    const passwordreal = `32°32′46″ N, 16°31′31″ W`
const form = document.getElementById("Formulario");//Añadido debido a una respuesta

    Username.addEventListener("input", function (event) {
      if (Username=="e") {
        if (password==passwordreal){
          location.href='https://www.youtube.com/c/OnlineTutorials4Designers/videos'//Links de prueba
        }else{
          location.href='https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCe8xYIQ3m5hzJ0M2fzp9AEw/videos'
        }
      } else {//Sigue llegando a este else
        location.href='https://www.youtube.com/c/MrBeast6000'
      }
    });
form.addEventListener("submit", function (event) {
  e.preventDefault()
});//Añadido debido a la respuesta, no funciona.
```

```css
    :root{
        --input-color: #80868B;
      --border-color: #DADCE0;
    }
    body {
        background-image: url("https://64.media.tumblr.com/bd1b0d977b3e43cc5645297d5322662c/tumblr_ndyybljlWc1rvnh7zo1_r1_500.gif");
        overflow: hidden;
        height: 100vh;
        background-size: cover;
        background-position: center;
      }
                  /* Centrar elemento dentro de main */
      .main {
       position: absolute;
       margin: auto;
       left: 0; right: 0;
       top: 0; bottom: 0;
       width: 1404px/*550px*/;
       height: 658px/*315px*/; line-height: 50px; /* Con «line-height» con el mismo valor numérico de la altura centras horizontalmente el texto */
      
      }
      .video{
          width: 1370px;
       height: 770px;
      }
      .icon {
        position: absolute;
        right: 0;
        /* top: 0; */
        bottom: 0;
        width: 3vw;
        height: 97vh;
    }
    .input {
      position: relative;
      background-color: var(--container-color);
      padding: 1.35rem 1.25rem;
      border-radius: .5rem;
      display: flex;
      align-items: center;
      column-gap: .75rem;
    }

    .input__lock, .input__icon {
      font-size: 1.25rem;
      z-index: 1;
    }


    .input__lock, .input__password {
      color: var(--white-color);
    }

    .input__icon {
      color: var(--first-color);
      cursor: pointer;
      position: absolute;
      right: 0.5vw;
      top: 1.5vh;
    }

    .input__password {
      background: transparent;
      border: none;
      outline: none;
      font-size: 14px;
      z-index: 1;
    }

    .input__password::placeholder {
      color: var(--white-color);
    }

    .input__overlay {
      width: 32px;
      height: 32px;
      background-color: var(--white-color);
      position: absolute;
      right: .9rem;
      border-radius: 50%;
      z-index: 0;
      transition: .4s ease-in-out;
    }

    /* Transition effect */
    .overlay-content {
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      border-radius: .5rem;
      right: 0;
    }

    .overlay-content ~ .input__lock {
      color: var(--container-color);
    }

    .overlay-content ~ .input__password,
    .overlay-content ~ .input__password::placeholder {
      color: var(--text-color);
    }
    .form{
      width: 360px;
      padding: 4rem 2rem;
      border-radius: 1rem;
    }
    .form__title{
      font-weight: 400;
      margin-bottom: 3rem;
    }
    .form__div{
      position: relative;
      height: 48px;
      margin-bottom: 1.5rem;
    }
    .input__icon {
      color: var(--first-color);
      cursor: pointer;
    }
    .form__input{
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      font-size: var(--normal-font-size);
      border: 1px solid var(--border-color);
      border-radius: .5rem;
      outline: none;
      padding: 1rem;
      background: none;
      z-index: 1;
      color: #f0f0f0;
    }
    .form__label{
      position: absolute;
      left: 1rem;
      top: 1rem;
      padding: 0 .25rem;
      background-color: var(--bs-dark-rgb);
      color: var(--input-color);
      font-size: var(--normal-font-size);
      transition: .3s;
    }
    .form__button{
      display: block;
      margin-left: auto;
      padding: .75rem 2rem;
      outline: none;
      background-color: transparent;
      color: #fff;
      font-size: var(--normal-font-size);
      border-radius: .5rem;
      cursor: pointer;
      transition: .3s;
    }
    .form__button:hover{
      box-shadow: 0 10px 36px rgba(0,0,0,.15);
    }

    /*Input focus mover arriba label*/
    .form__input:focus + .form__label{
      top: -.5rem;
      left: .8rem;
      color: var(--first-color);
      font-size: var(--small-font-size);
      font-weight: 500;
      z-index: 10;
      background-color: #212529;
    }

    /*Input focus mantener arriba label*/
    .form__input:not(:placeholder-shown).form__input:not(:focus)+ .form__label{
      top: -.5rem;
      left: .8rem;
      font-size: var(--small-font-size);
      font-weight: 500;
      z-index: 10;
      background-color: #212529;
    }

    /*Input focus*/
    .form__input:focus{
      border: 1.5px solid var(--first-color);
    }

    .bx2 {
      font-family: boxicons!important;
      font-weight: 400;
      font-style: normal;
      font-variant: normal;
      /*line-height: 3.5;*/
      text-rendering: auto;
      /*display: inline-block;*/
      text-transform: none;
      -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
      position: absolute;
      /* right: 23px; */
      left: 19rem;
      top: 0.80rem;
      -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
    }

    .img-content{
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      object-fit: cover;
      display: block;
    }

    .img-content:hover{
      cursor: pointer;
    }
    /*====================================================================================*/

    .box2 img {
      object-fit: fill;
    }
```

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/estilo1.css">
            <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">
            <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Spectral+SC:400,600" rel="stylesheet">
            <script type="module" src="https://unpkg.com/ionicons@5.5.2/dist/ionicons/ionicons.esm.js"></script>
            <script nomodule src="https://unpkg.com/ionicons@5.5.2/dist/ionicons/ionicons.js"></script>
            <title>Prueba</title>
            <!--=============== BOXICONS ===============-->
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/boxicons@latest/css/boxicons.min.css">
        </head>
        <body>
            <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ka7Sk0Gln4gmtz2MlQnikT1wXgYsOg+OMhuP+IlRH9sENBO0LRn5q+8nbTov4+1p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.10.2/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-7+zCNj/IqJ95wo16oMtfsKbZ9ccEh31eOz1HGyDuCQ6wgnyJNSYdrPa03rtR1zdB" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-QJHtvGhmr9XOIpI6YVutG+2QOK9T+ZnN4kzFN1RtK3zEFEIsxhlmWl5/YESvpZ13" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
            <div class="icon">
                <a href="#uploads" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#uploads"><ion-icon name="reorder-four-outline" size="large"></ion-icon></a>

            </div>
            <div class="main">
            </div>
            <!--Modal-->
            <div class="modal fade" id="uploads" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true" style="display: none;">
                <div class="modal-dialog bg-dark">
                  <div class="modal-content bg-dark">
                    <div class="modal-header bg-dark">
                      <h5 class="modal-title bg-dark" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
                      <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                          <div class="card text-white bg-dark mb-3" style="max-width: 80rem;">
                            <h3 style="color:#ffffff" class="card-header"><i class="far fa-image" aria-hidden="true"></i>Login</h3>
                            <div class="card-body">
                              <form id="Formulario" target="_self" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" autocomplete="off" onKeyPress="if (event.which == 13) return false;">
                                  <br>
                                  <div class="form__div">
                                    <input id="Username" type="text" class="form__input" placeholder=" " autofocus name="Email">
                                    <label for="" class="form__label">Username</label>
                                  </div>
                
                                <div class="form__div">
                                    <div class="input__overlay" id="input-overlay"></div>
                                    <input type="password" placeholder=" " class="form__input" id="input-pass" name="Password" onKeyPress="if (event.which == 13) return false;">
                                    <label for="" class="form__label">Password</label>
                                    <i class='bx bx-hide input__icon' id="input-icon"></i>
                                </div>
                                  <br>
                                <script>
                                    /*=============== SHOW / HIDDEN INPUT ===============*/
    const showHiddenInput = (inputOverlay, inputPass, inputIcon) =>{
        const overlay = document.getElementById(inputOverlay),
              input = document.getElementById(inputPass),
              iconEye = document.getElementById(inputIcon)
              
        iconEye.addEventListener('click', () =>{
            // Change password to text
            if(input.type === 'password'){
                // Switch to text
                input.type = 'text'

                // Change icon
                iconEye.classList.add('bx-show')
            }else{
                // Change to password
                input.type = 'password'

                // Remove icon
                iconEye.classList.remove('bx-show')
            }

            // Toggle the overlay
            overlay.classList.toggle('overlay-content')
        })
    }

    showHiddenInput('input-overlay','input-pass','input-icon')
                                </script>
                                  <br>
                                  <div class="form-group">
                                      <button class="btn btn-outline-light">
                                          <i class="fa fa-upload" aria-hidden="true"></i>Subir Imagen
                                      </button>
                                      <script src="./js/ValidacionInicio.js"></script>
                                  </div>
                              </form>
                          </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <!--Fin Modal-->
        </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Con el evento `input` se realiza la verificación cada que se hagan cambios en el campo `Username`. Lo ideal sería ejecutar la función al enviar el formulario y creo que la respuesta de @2coolDevs va bien encaminada.

Answer (score 2):

El atributo action indica la página a la que se envían los datos del formulario. Si este atributo está vacío, es la página que contiene el formulario la que se recargará con los datos como parámetros.

Elimina el atributo  action y si quieres que no se recargue la página al hacer submit del formulario has lo siguiente:

```js
const miFormulario = document.querySelector('.claseDeMiFormulario')
miFormulario.addEventListener("submit",(e) => {
  e.preventDefault()
)
```

El e.preventDefault() previene el comportamiento por defecto de un elemento, en este caso evitará que se envié el formulario, por ende no se recargará la página.